# Interception of competing businesses phone calls

Tags: privacy

A business competitor has shared that he is using some sort of app that is allowing him to intercept phone calls to other like businesses. This app has allowed him to enter those business numbers and to have incoming calls to those businesses forward to his personal cell. It's as though he has created a rogue tower which has allowed him to intercept all calls coming into these businesses without their knowledge. Mine is one of those numbers. He mentions using a jail broken phone but does not disclose the name of the app, etc. What is this he is doing?

Answer (score 1):

I'm very sure that's not (just) an app.

There are two practical ways to intercept calls:

- Malware
- Rogue celltower (IMSI catcher)

Both are highly illegal. The first one requires targeting those people's phones with viruses, the second one's very expensive and only local.

You hint he's able to select multiple business numbers.
Now it's unlikely he's placed boxes at each of these locations, and a little more likely he's paid some hackers a bitcoin to target the businesses.

You remember any office documents in your mail asking you to enable macros?

Answer (score 0):

If he really is using an IMSI catcher, it should be fairly easy to detect. You can get apps that will let you know what cell towers are nearby and see their ID's. As it is unlikely that he keeps this running 24x7, you would be able to see the extra "tower" coming and going. Once you know he really is doing that and not just shooting his mouth off, report him and your evidence direct to the authorities who naturally take a rather dim view of such things.

Personally, I expect that he is lying through his teeth and isn't actually doing anything at all. In that case, the better approach would be to anonymously spread rumours about his claims through social media - it is fairly likely that his foolish claims would then rebound on him.